# Unable to use ActionBarSherlock library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have Created a new android project from existing source(ActionBarSherlock library) with API 15. I added this library to my project(**Project properties -> android -> library-> add ->com_actionbarsherlock ->apply ->ok**).But When I again see (Project properties -> android -> library->) **com_actionbarsherlock is showing red color cross**.So, I am unable to import the library classes.I am really struggling with this. I have attached two screen shots Screen Shot When I add library and Screen Shot After library is added.
Any help would be appreciate.[image: Screen Shot When I add library]
[image: Screen Shot After library is added]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ActionBarSherlock v4.0` or above, you need to build your project against API 15.