# Same App for both tablet and phone in android

Tags: android, tablet, android-actionbar

I want to develop single app for both tablet and phone. So for fragments I am using android-support-v4 compatability jar and app runs on both tablet and phone with all versions. Now, I want to use action bar with tabs in my app and on googling I got ActionBarCompat sample app .
I converted it to library and added to my project. But I dont know how to use this library in my project for creating action bar . 
How can I  use this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

[ActionBar Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

[ActionbarSherlock for compatibility on older devices](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713886/unable-to-use-actionbarsherlock-library